# infobip chatbot fetching data

Tags: infobip, infobip-api

```
TypeError: invokeMember (get) on com.infobip.bot.engine.anticorruption.external.coding.execution.CodingAttributeApi@5c7c1bc1 failed due to: Arity error - expected: 1 actual: 2
```

found a error while fetching data from  api.

i hit a api got back the response code 200.
data was not getting set  in a infobip variable .

```
  let list = attributeApi.get('getavailablity');
  attributeApi.set('departure_time',list[8-1].dT );
  attributeApi.get('return_time', list[8-1].aT);
  attributeApi.set('total_amount', list[8-1].totalAmount);
```

Answer (score 0):

Just change:

```
attributeApi.get('return_time', list[8-1].aT);
```

to:

```
attributeApi.set('return_time', list[8-1].aT);
```